# Contador zerando sem motivo

Tags: java, android

Estou com um método no qual toda vez que ele for acionado, além de realizar outras operações, um determinado contador `cont` deve ser incrementado e depois chamar outro método em que irá verificar se o contador é maior do que zero.

---

O problema é que quando ele verifica se é maior do que zero e deve ser quando o método que incrementa é chamado, mas o **contador** automaticamente **volta a ser zero sem nenhuma razão** e retorna o comando que deve ser realizado quando ele é zero.

---

**Método que incrementa o contador**

```
public void enviar(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "O cadastro foi realizado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    Intent telaInicial = new Intent(this, Principal.class);
    startActivity(telaInicial);
    this.cont++;
    qntProd();
}
```

**Método que verifica**

```
public String qntProd() { 
    if(this.cont > 0) {
        return "Você possui " + this.cont + " produtos cadastrados";
    }else {
        return "Você não possui produtos cadastrados";
    }
}
```

**A classe principal que chama o método *qntProd()***

```
public class Principal extends Activity {
    private TextView produtosCadastrados;
    private String retorno;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
        produtosCadastrados = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.produtosCadastrados);
        //qntProd = produtos.qntProd();
        Cadastrar cadastrar = new Cadastrar();
        retorno = cadastrar.qntProd(cadastrar.cont);
        produtosCadastrados.setText(retorno);
        /*if(cadastrar.cont > 0) {
            produtosCadastrados.setText("Você possui " + cadastrar.cont + " produtos cadastrados.");
        }else {
            produtosCadastrados.setText("Você não possui produtos cadastrados.");
        }*/     
    }
    public void cadastra(View view) {
        Intent telaCadastra = new Intent(this, Cadastrar.class);
        startActivity(telaCadastra);
    }

}
```

---

**Código recomendado**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
        produtosCadastrados = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.produtosCadastrados);
        Intent it = getIntent();
        int cont = it.getIntExtra("valor", 0);
        it.putExtra("valor", cont);
        if(cont > 0) {
            retorno = "Você possui " + String.valueOf(cont) + " produtos cadastrados";
        }else {
            retorno = "Você não possui produtos cadastrados";
        }
        produtosCadastrados.setText(retorno);

    }
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80054/discussion-on-question-by-marcos-paulo-s-rezende-contador-zerando-sem-motivo)

Answer (score 1):

**Erro:** Quando você termina de executar o método enviar você abre uma nova activity e dentro de seu método OnCreate você instancia novamente a classe Cadastrar (new Cadastrar()) com isso o contador novamente é criado com 0 e isso se repete sempre, você não salva o contador, simplesmente cria outra instância e tenta verificar, ou seja, nunca seu contador vai ser maior que 0.

**Sugestão:** Como você não está persistindo os dados, não aconselho criar uma nova activity, toda vez que ele entrar no método enviar retorne um boolean, se o método retornar TRUE significa que a activity pode ser limpa, com isso você limpa os dados da tela e deixa o contador na activity, com isso o contador vai ser uma instância só.